Creating a winform ironpython 3 Project in VSCode Community 2019
I have no clue what i am doing wrong
I have ironpython and winforms installed and vscode sees both
I don't have any options for IronPython Project when creating a new project, what can i do to have IronPython Templates.
How to create a new WinForms IronPython Project?
I tried changing the default Python Interpreter.

May I ask what happened when you changed the default Python interpreter?
Generally, I'd say that you'd need to point VScode to the IronPython interpreter.
Just edit the settings.json file and set the python.pythonPath to the path of your ipy.exe. I believe it should be in your IronPython installation directory.
There aren't really any templates for IronPython WinForms, so you might have to make these files manually.
Good luck, and I hope this helped.
